# Можно ли читать - кропотливо?

Tags: пунктуация, лексика, выбор-слов

> Что уж тут про работу с источниками говорить. Вот прочитала я труд
>   Чекалевского. Эстетический трактат XVIII века, адресованный студентам
>   русской Академии художеств. С превеликим удовольствием! Чрезвычайно
>   любопытно! Труд компилятивный, очень много из Винкельмана, и вот прямо
>   сейчас меня мучает то, что **я ведь недавно кропотливо прочла подряд
>   несколько итальянских трактатов** XIV века, и смотрю: кусочки-то
>   оттуда наш уважаемый Чекалевский потырил, да ссылок на источники-то не
>   дал! Нехорошо, право слово. Статью бы об этом написать! Однако уличить – не могу. Забыла, где прочитала.

Про запятые тоже отзовитесь, пожалуйста. На уровне *нравится - не нравится*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сочетание допустимое.

**КРОПОТЛИВЫЙ**,  1. Требующий много внимания, усилий, терпения. К-ая работа. К. труд. К-ые розыски в архивах. К-ое дело

**Читать кропотливо** – это читать старательно, усердно, прилежно, **останавливаясь на деталях, изучая их**.

А текст я написала бы так:

Что уж тут про работу с источниками говорить. Вот ознакомилась  я трудом Чекалевского. Эстетический трактат XVIII века, адресованный студентам русской Академии художеств. С превеликим удовольствием! Чрезвычайно любопытно! Труд компилятивный, очень много из Винкельмана.  И вот теперь вспомнила, что я ведь недавно кропотливо (внимательно, старательно, усердно, прилежно, терпеливо) прочла подряд несколько итальянских трактатов XIV века. И смотрю: кусочки-то оттуда наш уважаемый Чекалевский потырил, да ссылок на источники-то не дал! Нехорошо, право слово. Статью бы об этом написать! Однако уличить – не могу. Забыла, где прочитала.

**В заданном тексте** нет нужной смысловой разбивки, да  и переход от коротких предложения к одному длинному не кажется обоснованным.

Answer (score 1):

Можно прочитать, *кропотливо* разбирая каракули (напр. в интересах точного прочтения чего-то неясно написанного) или кропотливо извлекая заложенный смысл, - это о тексте, прочтение которого требует **трудовых** усилий. Чтобы в сочетании с "кропотливый" глагол прочитать выглядел естественно, нужно предварительно сказать о трудностях чтения упомянутого текста. А здесь наоборот, ранее сказано о чтении *с удовольствием*, поэтому "кропотливо" звучит неубедительно (можно было сказать "внимательно").

Answer (score 0):

> Что уж тут про работу с источниками говорить.

Что уж тут о работе с источниками говорить!

> ... студентам русской Академии художеств.

Студентам Российской Академии художеств.

> ... недавно кропотливо прочла подряд несколько итальянских трактатов XIV века.

Недавно не один итальянский трактат XIV в. проштудировала.

> ... потырил, да ссылок на источники-то не дал!

Умыкнул, а ссылок-то на источники и не дал!

Comment: shampar, что ж ты за змий такой?! О_о "Нет предела совершенству". Нельзя подменять собой автора!